# Late application for UK settled status due to "compassionate reason"

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-settlement-scheme

I lived in the United Kingdom from September 2010 to June 2020 almost completely uninterrupted (save for about 2-3 months every year when I returned to my home country, Greece). At the time of leaving, I was aware of the complexities that Brexit would bring to immigration, and I was aware of the pre-settled and settled scheme, but because I was planning to relocate to Italy for a long-term (but not permanent) position, I did not apply, being under the mistaken impression that I would lose my settled status upon leaving the UK.

I ended up leaving the UK amidst the COVID-19 pandemic and relocated to Italy and then Greece where I reside now.

I very recently became aware of my mistake. I learnt that not only was I entitled at the time to apply for settled status, I would not have even lost it up until 2025 since it lasts for 5 years. Now of course the deadline has long passed, but the UK Border Agency still offers the possibility of applying beyond the deadline for settled status "with good reason".

I have completed the identity check, and I am looking at the application. The question/request that troubles me is "Choose your main reason for making an application after the deadline." The form offers a list of possible answers, many of which do not apply to me (not being of age at the time, mental illness, etc). I think that my reason (foolish though it may be), if accepted, would fall under what they call "Practical or compassionate reason". I reproduce the ones that could conceivably be relevant to what I described:

> I was unaware of the requirement to apply by the deadline

> I have lived in the UK for a long time and did not realise I needed to apply

> I was unable to apply by the deadline due to issues associated with the COVID-19 pandemic

> I was unable to apply by the deadline due to another practical or compassionate reason

I suppose my question pertains to how I should frame my original blunder in this application (I understand there will be a space in the application later on to further elaborate). Does this even count as a "compassionate reason"? I want to be truthful and fully own up to my misunderstanding (ignorance of the law and all that), but I still would like to know what the best approach to this would be.

Comment: TBH I’m not sure that “ I was planning to relocate to Italy for a long-term” and “I misunderstood the rules” would count - if the latter counted, everyone who missed the deadline would claim it as a reason. See https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1149607/EU_Settlement_Scheme_EU_other_EEA_Swiss_citizens_and_family_members.pdf#page44 for some guidance.IMHO you’d probably do better to get advice from an immigration lawyer.

Comment: "I was planning to relocate to Italy for a long-term position" To clarify, it was a two-year fixed-term contract position, not permanent by any means. I understand this is a difficult issue, and I've already planned an appointment with a lawyer.

Comment: Further: page 44 of the linked PDF from the Home Office mentions "living overseas" before the deadline as an acceptable practical reason, which sounds like it applies to my situation (I was not in the UK in the months before 30 June 2021). I will be mentioning this and all relevant details to a lawyer.